# Multiprocessing: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread pyside

Tags: pyside, opencv3.0, python-multiprocessing, pool, qimage

I am building a simple GUI and trying to learn multiprocessing. In my GUI the capture button captures a frame and puts it inside the gui within a frame or a declared space(Qlabel). I did read the other posts in SO but didn't quiet understand how to use it in my program.

When the error said not safe to use outside GUI, I tried

```
    print(multiprocessing.current_process())
```

which indicates that my QPixmap is running in the main thread. This is my program

```
import examplegui
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Queue

def image_capture():
    print(multiprocessing.current_process())
    print("starting img proc")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 641)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 351)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()

    if ret == True:
        cv2.imwrite('frame.png', frame)
        return frame

class Maindialog(QMainWindow,examplegui.Ui_MainWindow):
    pass_arguments = Signal(list)

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Maindialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        self.connect(self.excel_file,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.apply_connection)
    # self.pass_arguments.connect


    def apply_connection(self):
        print(multiprocessing.current_process())
        result = self.pool.apply_async(image_capture,callback=self.show_img)

    def show_img(self,result):
        print(multiprocessing.current_process())
        # print(result.type)
        cv2.imshow("img",result)
        image = QImage(result, result.shape[1], result.shape[0], result.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.vidimg.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))            
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Maindialog()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I did an cv2.imshow to make sure the image is being run,but I need that image inside the GUI.When I run the prog I get the error

```
 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

[image]

Comment: did the answer fix your issue Raghavendra?

Comment: @ZF007 Not really ! But I used threading to go around this error and that works fine for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`self.pool.apply_async` runs each callback (`self.show_img`) in a Python thread, otherwise it would block the main thread and not be asynchronous!

Note that you've only checked the callbacks see being run in the main process, not the main thread of thay process.